# C# Syntax to Create JSchema with If multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, validation, jsonschema

```
JSchema schema = new JSchema();
        schema.Type = JSchemaType.Object;
        schema.AllowAdditionalProperties = true;

        schema.Required.Add("Gender");
        schema.Required.Add("Single Girl Child");
        schema.Properties.Add("Gender",
           new JSchema()
           {
               Type = JSchemaType.String,
               AnyOf = {
                new JSchema{
                    Title = "MALE",
                    Pattern = GeneratePattern("male")
                    },
                new JSchema{
                    Title = "FEMALE",
                    Pattern =GeneratePattern("female")
                    },
                new JSchema{
                    Title = "THIRD GENDER",
                    Pattern =GeneratePattern("third gender")
                    }
               }
           }
       );
        schema.Properties.Add("Single Girl Child",
            new JSchema()
            {
                Type = JSchemaType.String,
                AnyOf = {
                new JSchema{
                    Title = "Yes",
                    Pattern = GeneratePattern("Yes")
                    },
                new JSchema{
                    Title = "No",
                    Pattern =GeneratePattern("No")
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        return schema.ToString();
```

The Above code creates Json Schema. I need to add IF condition on "SINGLE GIRL CHILD" property wherein if YES then the "GENDER" should be FEMALE.

I need to validate if Single Girl Child is YES then Gender show be Female.
I need the syntax to create conditional JSchema.

Comment: Welcome! You should include your code IN your question, not use an external image (best to not use an image at all for code). If the external image vanished, your question would be useless to others.

Comment: Relequestual: Noted*